# LyX BibTeX with child-documents not working

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx

If I insert the bibliography within the child document, it works perfectly. (therefore  it cannot be the Databank). But when I try to render the parent document, I get the following error:

```
 \citep
           {NatalieJ.Sayer:2007}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

[image]

Comment: have you used `\usepackage{natbib}`?

Comment: Sir, send me your bank account so that I can transfer you two gillion dollars :). That was exactly the problem, thanks a lot. Post it as an answer so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `natbib` package you get access to different `\cite` commands, such as `\citet` and `\citep`.

Simply add it to your preamble by typing:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

For more information, please refer to the `natbib` [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf)